# OAuth callback url for iOS

Tags: oauth, callback

i have an app that i have devloped in xCode 4.5 and using phonegap. I wanted to connect to twitter and dropbox and i registered my app, i'm using childBrowser and oAuth.js to do the authorization.
The problem i'm having is what do i set the callback url to be for my app?
I've seen on some sites to create a url scheme in your plist, which i did called 'myapp://' and when i open safari in my phone and type this in it launches my app, however when i pass this to dropbox or twitter nothing happens, that is control is never returned to my app.

Help please!!

Comment: have you specified the callback url in your requesttoken method..